# Populate drop down list dynamically from .txt file via .php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have searched before posting but have struggled to find a solution to my problem below.

I have built an HTML form (with a form builder) and need to get information in one page into a dropdown box on the next page, the inputs on page one consist of six levels of payrate that a user would enter.
I then need to get those payrates into a dropdown on page 2 to use in calculations on that page.
I came across a few scripts but they seem to need to pull the info from a database or text file, in my project I have neither, only the live data in the boxes in a .php file which is linked to the .txt templates. ie 1 .php page populated by 6 txt files as you click through the pages of the form.
Can anyone suggest a way of doing this? The page does have the following scripts in it;

```
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!--script src='scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <!--script src='scripts/globalize.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='scripts/jquery.sim.number.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='scripts/jquery.sim.utils.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: a framework like VueJS could bind that data to an array which could bind live to your dropdown on the same page. You could also go the jquery route and have the button populate an array and generate the dropdown on the same page while hiding the original div that held your first form.

Comment: you can send the values in POST.

Comment: you can use AJAX to post the data onto another page

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, really appreciate them. What would be the easiest of your suggestions for a rookie to use?

Comment: Variations of "How to populate a drop-down/select list dynamically" and "How to get data from one page to another page" are two of the _most frequently asked questions_ on Stackoverflow. In the _Search_ box at the top of this page I typed "dynamically populate dropdown list" and got over 600 results on SO. I'm sure if you search some more you can find several good answers to your questions.

Comment: @StephenP, I did look at loads of them but none seemed to cover the specific (.php page with .txt templates) that I was facing. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page  1

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action ="a.html"  method 
= "get" name = "payrate" id = 
"payrate"> Payrate 
<br/>

Level 1

<input type = "text" name = 
"field1" id = "field1" />
<br/>

Level 2
<input type = "text" name = 
"field1" id = "field1" />
<br/>

Level 3
<input type = "text" name = 
"field1" id = "field1" />
<br/>

Level 4
<input type = "text" name = 
"field1" id = "field1" />
<br/>

Level 5
<input type = "text" name = 
"field1" id = "field1" />
<br/>

Level 6
<input type = "text" name = 
"field1" id = "field1" />
<br/>
<input type = "submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2

```
<body>

<div>
<select>
<option class = 'dropdown'> 
</option>
<option class = 'dropdown'> 
</option>
<option class = 'dropdown'> 
</option>
<option class = 'dropdown'> 
</option>
<option class = 'dropdown'> 
</option>
<option class = 'dropdown'>   
</option>
</select>

</div>


<script> 


//get the value of each field 
from the url as a query string
var query = location.search; 
var splitQuery = []; var value 
= [];

function parseQuery(query){

/*check if there are 
mutiple value (querystring in 
url are seperated with &), and 
store them to an associative 
array*/

if(query.search(/[&]/)){
splitQuery = query.split('&');

/*split again and target drop 
down*/ 

for (var x = 0; x < 
splitQuery.length; x++){
var splitEach = 
splitQuery[x].split('=');

document.getElementsByClassName
('dropdown')[x].textContent = 
splitEach[1];       
}   
} 
} 
parseQuery(query); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, what you need is

1. To send your pay rate on page one as query string in the url using
   GET method and send formdata to page 2.
2. On page two you get this data using the 'location.search' method,
   you could parse it to collect individual payrate using regex 'split'
   method.
3. The using DOM, target the individual options in the HTML input
   select tag you created and update their text content. Hope this
   helps